# Limiting autoshape movement in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question here, so try not to be harsh.

I am trying to create an excel sheet, which does the following:

1. reads information from the database through the custom defined class
2. using the read specifications, it creates autoshapes and puts them in first sheet

Is there any way to get information when someone changes the autoshapes (ie, resizes or moves them)? I thought about using built in events - but non of them works for me. Can I limit autoshape movement in any other way?

This sheet needs to be done in Microsoft Office 2003.

I would be grateful for any help.

Best regards,
Mike.

**[edit]

I think than I have found a partial solution - I will test if it works, and if yes - I will post it here.**

Answer (score 1):

No there are no events that apply to shapes. The best you could do is use the existing events - like SheetChange, SheetSelectionChange, WorkbookBeforeSave etc.

Then loop through the Sheet.Shapes collection checking for changes and revert them.
You will have to know the original size and locations.

**Have you thought of just locking them and protecting the sheet?**

Comment: Thank You for the response. Too bad that there are no events which are connected with shapes - I must now think about another way in which I can limit their movement. Locking the sheet is not the point - I want them only to be limited, not locked. 
Thank You one more time.